# Scala: Creating a dataframe from a series of lists

Tags: scala, apache-spark

i am trying to create a dataframe based on 4 lists i have. i have to use scala only (we can't use SQL for various reasons).

all lists have 3 values, and the column_head list is a list of the column names.

```
column_head =["a","b","c"]

master_in =[1,2,"dog"]

master_out =[3,4,"cat"]

master_max = [5,6,"llama"]
```

ive tried:

```
val values 
=Seq(columns_head,master_in,master_out,master_maxweight)

val master_df= values.toDF()
```

but i get an exception saying: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: scala.Any

This is likely because the last value of each list is a STRING value, whereas the first two for each list are INTEGERS.

How do I solve this problem?

I can't import any other libraries outside of:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.desc

import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

case class edges(Source: String, Target: String, Weight: Int)

import spark.implicits._
```

how do i make a df from the lists i have?

Comment: I saw you have first list is the header , in spark you could do write to csv for example with spark.sqlContext.createDataFrame(rdd, schema) and option("header", "true") //Write the header

Comment: I can't use SQL commands

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you are having stems from the type of data in the different columns.

Because there are both integers and a string in the data, you can't think of it as a list of lists. Well, you can, but then "inner" list will have an element type of `Any`, which is the closest shared ancestor of `Int` and `String`. Of course, Spark can't work with `Any`. It's too general.

The solution is simple: describe the type of data explicitly using a case class.

```
case class Data(a: Int, b: Int, c: String)

spark.createDataFrame(Seq(
  Data(1,2,"dog"), Data(3,4,"cat"), Data(5,6,"llama")
))
```